# CouchDB: How to change view function via javascript?

Tags: javascript, view, couchdb

I am playing around with [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) to test if it is "possible" [1] to store scientific data (simulated and experimental raw data + metadata). A big pro is the schema-less approach of CouchDB: we have to be very flexible with the metadata, as the set of parameters changes very often.

Up to now I have some code to feed raw data, plots (both as attachments), and hierarchical metadata (as JSON) into CouchDB documents, and have written some prototype Javascript for filtering and showing. But the filtering is done on the client side (a.k.a. browser): The map function simply returns everything.

How could I change the (or push a second) map function of a specific _design-document with simple browser-JS?

I do not think that a temporary view would yield any performance gain...

Thanks for your time and answers.

[1]: of course it is possible, but is it also useful? feasible? reasonable?

**[added]**

Ah, the jquery.couch.js (version 0.9.0) provides a saveDoc() function, which could update the _design document with the new map function.

But I also tried out the query function, which uses a temporary view. Okay, "do not use this in the real product, only during development"... But scientific research *is* steady development, right?

Temporary views are getting cached, as I noticed, and it works well for ~1000 documents per DB. A second plus: all users (think of 1 to 3, so a big user management is quit of an overkill) can work with their own temporary view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never *ever* use temporary views. They are really only there for dev and debugging purposes. For more information, see http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views (specifically the bold "NOTE").

And yes, because design documents are really just documents with special powers, you can run you GET/POST/PUT/DELETE methods on them. However, you will usually need admin privileges to do this. So, if you are allowing a client side piece of software to do that, you are making your entire database public for read/write access - this may be fine for your application, but is important to remember.

Ex., if you restrict access to your database, but put the username and password in client side javascript, then anyone can see that username and password.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve written an helper functions for jquery.couch and design docs, take a look at:

https://github.com/grischaandreew/jquery.couch.js